# Use AppleScript to toggle Settings

Tags: applescript

I will preface this by saying that scripting/coding/developing is not in my wheelhouse, so apologies in advance for my syntax/general lack of what I am doing.

I am trying to create a quick action, which runs and AppleScript I have written/cobbled together.

The goal is to turn on and off Do Not Disturb, and to turn on or off an indefinite session in the application Amphetamine so that my computer will no sleep. This is effectively, a toggle switch for before and after running a presentation on my computer..

Below is what I have:

```
tell application "Amphetamine"

if session is active end session

else

start new session

ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "d" using {command down, option down, control down}
end ignoring
```

I am getting errors which I don't understand."Expected “end” or “on” but found end of script." One note, That whole seres of keystrokes for DND was a suggestion I found here on Stack Overflow which said, create a keyboard shortcut for DND and invoke that via Apple Script.

My presumption was that my script says ––– Hey if Amphetamine is running a session, turn it off, otherwise start a session. And by the way, just toggle DND to the opposite state its in currently.

I am open to any suggestions to get the desired effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, using your method for toggling *Do Not Disturb* by way of the keyboard shortcut, and the builtin program called `caffeinate`, which does what *Amphetamine* does (and I wouldn't be surprised if that's what it's using under the hood).

[image: Screenshot of Automator Workflow]

It's quite busy to look at, but there's not actually too much going on.  The **Run Shell Script** action toggles `caffeinate` on/off, inverting the previous state.  When it's off, your system and display will behave as they normally do; when it's on, both the system and the display are prevented from idling or going to sleep--for the display, this means that it will stay on unless you actively choose to turn it off.  For example, I have a hot corner on my MacBook so that my mouse can shut off my display by moving to that corner; when my machine is *"caffeinated"*, I can turn the display off if I want by way of the hot corner, and close the clamshell lid, but the machine will still be operating away with slightly less risk of overheating.

The **Run AppleScript** action doesn't receive any input from the shell script--you can see they are not connected.  They do still run in sequence, however.  So once the caffeination status has been toggled, this is used to set the Do Not Disturb mode to be in line with the caffeination, i.e. if caffeinated, DND gets activated if it isn't already; if decaffeinated, DND gets deactivated if it is active.  In both cases, an alert pops up since notifications wouldn't be seen with DND active.  You can remove the code relating to displaying the alert if it's too intrusive--a subtle indication that DND is active is the icon for the notification centre in the taskbar will be dimmed.

[Here's a copy of the workflow](https://github.com/ChristoferK/bin/tree/master/Automator/Caffeinate.workflow) you can grab from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer to your question may be overdue, but while dealing with the same problem, I came across this issue, so I wanted to share how I solved it.

```
  tell application "Amphetamine"
     set sessionActiveTest to session is active
     if sessionActiveTest is false then
         tell application "Amphetamine" to start new session
     else
         tell application "Amphetamine" to end session
     end if
  end tell
```

Check this documentation:
https://iffy.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/48000078223-applescript-documentation